# change URL parameters on GET Form

Tags: php

How do i change my URL on GET form.  My form looks like this

```
<form method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="brand">
  <input type="text" name="model">
  <input type="text" name="condition">
  <input type="text" name="transmission">
  <input type="submit" name="search_car" value="SEARCH>
</form>

my url would look like this 

http://example.com/car-listings.php?make=Toyota&model=Vios&condition=New&transmission=Manual&search_car=SEARCH
```

i would like to shorten my URL parameters and change it like this

```
http://example.com/car-listings.php?make=Toyota&model=Vios
```

is there anyway i can modify my paraments on GET method?

Comment: Use post instead of get!

Comment: this is a search page on..1 page sir POST wont work it wont change the URL parameters

Comment: Why do you want to shorten it? And are you still expecting to get the other parameters, or do you want to remove them completely?

Comment: I just want to remove them sir i do not plan on getting them because my pagination will handle the parameter. I just want that after searching the URL parameters is shorten like the pagination URL 'example.com/car-listings.php?make=Toyota&model=Vios&page=2'

Comment: Simply check `_GET` parameters in php and just include the non empty parameters in the pagination url.

Comment: You can do this by javascript

Comment: if you disable the input with disabled-attribute, it won't get submitted via the form

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the following approach:

1. Let the form submitted normally without modification.
2. In your php code, filter the `_GET` array to get the non-empty parameters.
3. Generate the pagination URLs based on the resulted array from step 2.

Example:

```
<form method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="brand">
  <input type="text" name="model">
  <input type="text" name="condition">
  <input type="text" name="transmission">
  <input type="submit" value="SEARCH">
</form>

<?php

// Function to check if the $var value is empty or not.
function not_empty($var)
{
    return !empty($var) && !is_null($var) && isset($var);
}

// Step 1
if(!empty($_GET) && isset($_GET)){
    // Step 2, apply not_empty function with array_filter for each GET parameter, to get the non-empty list.
    $parameters = array_filter($_GET, 'not_empty');

    if(!empty($parameters) && isset($parameters)){
        // Step 3, Generate the pagination URLs
        $pagination_query = '';
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
            if($i == 0){
                $pagination_query .= "$key=$value";
            }else{
                $pagination_query .= "&$key=$value";
            }
            $i++;

        }

        echo "example.com/car-listings.php?".$pagination_query."&page=2";
    }   
}
```